# Start Application from inside Service

Tags: java, android

I have a service that have to start an application and count every 15 second.

I create `AlarmManager` and call the service every 15 second.The problem is when i push the start button program start service class and open application and start to count, but when i push stop button the application get error

`"Unfortunately, Program has stopped."`

After that the program automatically start to counting and opening the application
and i can't stop that.

I can't figure out. any help or something new can do this. thanks.

***Myservice.java***

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Myservice extends Service{

    int counter=0;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {

        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
    {

          super.onStart(intent, startId);

          Startapp();

          counter++;

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Start : " + counter,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    public void onDestroy()
    {

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          super.onDestroy();

    }


    public void Startapp()

    {   
        Intent in = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.application");
        startActivity(in);  

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Counter : " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {




     Intent myIntent;
     PendingIntent pendingIntent;
     AlarmManager alarmManager;

     Button btn1;
     Button btn2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);




        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Clash.class);

                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 7778, myIntent, 0);

                alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

                calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),15000, pendingIntent);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                pendingIntent.cancel();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });



}
```

Comment: delete pendingIntent.cancel();

Comment: @kozaxinan I try to remove  pendingIntent.cancel(); but still nothing

Comment: call alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); before alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); and check pendingIntent for null.

Comment: @kozaxinan i try your suggestion. now i don't have get any error,but after click stop button,program still counting and start application, it seems service is open but when i click on stop button it show "Service Destroy"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this flag:

```
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

So your `Startapp` method will look like this:

```
public void Startapp()
{   
    Intent in = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.application");
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(in);  

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Counter : " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working....set in stop button...always cancel pending intent after creating it

```
 alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);


    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 7778, myIntent, 0);

            try {
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ex....."+e);
            }

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),10000, pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 7778, myIntent, 0);
            try {
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ex....."+e);
            }
            MainActivity.this.stopService(myIntent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: vote up plz..if its helpful...so that other can use too

Comment: Sorry i'm new, my reputation is 0.